# C++ for loop with char type

Tags: c++, loops

>The character `'b'` is `char('a'+1),'c' is char('a'+2)`,etc. Use a loop to write out a table of characters with their corresponding integer values.
I cannot finish this exercise because of this error.
error: **lvalue required as  increment operand**

```
  for(char a='a'; a<24; ++a)
    {
    cout<<char('a'++);
    }
```

Comment: You confound your variable `a` with the literal char `'a'`.

Comment: Your first sentence is true of ASCII, but not of some other encodings.

Comment: @chris I understand it's a citation from the assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop body will never execute with the controlling expression `a < 24` because you have initialized variable `a` with character `a` and all printable characters are not less than ASCII value 32.
Try this:

```
for(char a='a'; a < 'a' + 24; ++a)
{
    cout << a;
}
```

Comment: Why not print the last letter of the alphabet ? ^_^

Comment: @Jarod42; Because OP wants to do in this way :P

Comment: @Jarod42 Nobody mentioned an alphabet. A particular language's alphabet is quite far removed as a concept from a character set encoding, which is the domain of this question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would be less confused if you named your variable `letter` instead of `a`, because it only represents the letter 'a' at the very beginning.

```
for(char letter='a'; letter<24; ++letter)
{
  cout<<char('a'++);
}
```

I'm going to assume you actually want to print out the entire alphabet, not just the first 24 letters.

It looks from here like you tried to do a mix of two possible approaches. In the first approach, you increment a `char` from `a` to `z` with each iteration of the `for` loop and print it out each time. In the second approach, you increment some offset from `0` to `25` and print out `'a' + offset`.

You mix these two approaches up in the first line. You're starting the loop with `letter` set to `'a'`, which you do not know the numerical value of. You then compare `letter` to see if it is less than `24`. Well in any ASCII-compatible character set, the character `'a'` has value `97`, so this condition will never pass.

You then misuse `++` on the `cout` line. The `++` operator attempts to modify its operand, yet `'a'` is a literal and so cannot be modified. Have a look at what your assignment told you. You can do `'a' + 1` to get `'b'`, for example, so this assumes you have an offset (which you don't with your current approach).

So to repeat, you have two options. First: keep `letter` as a `char` starting at `'a'` and fix the condition so that it checks if `letter` is less than or equal to the value of `'z'` and then just print out `letter`. Second: change `letter` to `offset` and start it off at `0` and increment it while it is less than `26`, and then print out `'a' + offset`.

Note, however, that both of these approaches assume that the letters have consecutive values in the execution character set. This is not necessarily true.

Comment: all i can understand is the codes :D im just a newbie in programming :(

Comment: @user3687358 I can tell, which is why I explained it all.

Comment: @user3687358 Ask me what?

Comment: @user3687358 I don't understand what you're saying or asking.

Answer (score 1):

The ++ operator is a "hidden assignment" (the operand's value is changed by it). But you can only assign to variables, which 'a' is not.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been closed for a while but since the exercise was about while loops and not for loops, I thought I would offer my solution. I'm just going through the book myself and someone in the future might stumble over this.

```
int i = 0;
char n = 'a';   // this will list the alphabet
int conv = 0;   
conv = n;       // this converts the alphabet into integer

while (i < 26) {        // starts from 0 and goes to 25
    cout << char(n + i) << '\t' << conv + i << '\n';
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: The question has not been closed. It has already been answered. If you feel like you can contribute, feel free to do so :) Btw, you cannot post on closed questions.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following: (http://ideone.com/akwGhl)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; ++c) {
        std::cout << "letter " << c << " has value " << int(c) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey through troubleshooting i obtained a sample that worked , i have yet to perfectly understand how my code works but as the solutions that were proposed to me here seemed too technical for my level i figured that i should publish mine

```
#include"header files . h"//i use the libraries given in the book
int main () {
    char a ='a';
    int i = 0 ;
    while (i <= 25)//for (i = 0 ; i <= 25 ; i++)
//for those who used for
{
        cout << a << '\t' << 'a' + i << endl;
        a += 1; // augments the character value of a to b ... then to z

        i++; // augments the value of i allowing us thus to make the augmentation,if you are using the for structure do not put I in your code
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).